# Something is wrong with my while not in loop, but i cant figure out what it is

Tags: python

I have this code for a beginners Rock Paper Scissors python game (I just started learning and I only know very basic stuff)

```
play_again = True
while (play_again):

   import random
   import time
   
   rps = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")
   user = None #makes it so "user" can be called in while loop
   computer = random.choice(rps) #Picks 1 random option from the options variable
   
   while user not in rps: #if user enters something other than one of the options, prompts again
      user = input("Enter a choice: rock, paper, or scissors? ==> ")
   
   #print(user)
   #print(computer)
   
      if user == computer:
         print("You Chose: " + user)
         print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
         print("It's a tie!")
      elif (user == "rock" and computer == "scissors") or (user == "paper" and computer == "rock") or (user == "scissors" and computer == "paper"):
         print("You Chose: " + user)
         print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
         print("You win!")
      elif (user == "scissors" and computer == "rock") or (user == "rock" and computer == "paper") or (user == "paper" and computer == "scissors"):
         print("You Chose: " + user)
         print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
         print("You lost ;(")
         
      print() 
         
      question = None
      play_again_options = ("yes", "no")
      while question not in play_again_options:
         question = input("Do you want to play again? Type 'yes' or 'no' ==> ")
         if (question == "yes"):
            play_again = True
            print()
         elif (question == "no"):
            play_again = False
```

"while user not in rps" is supposed to re-prompt the user to input of the 3 options, rock, paper or scissors, if they enter something other than one of the options, but when I enter something that is not in options, instead of re-promting for that input, it skips it and moves down to the second while loop "while question not in play_again_options:"

[image: example of what happens]

everything else works fine, the game itself, the play again, its just this one thing thats been bugging me.

I know it has something to do with the second while loop at the bottom, "while question not in play_again_options:", because when I comment it out the other while loop works perfectly fine.

Comment: Your indentation is off -- the `if user == computer` and everything below it should be unindented one level so it's outside of the `while user not in rps` loop.  (Also, your indentation is 3 spaces, which is unusual and makes it just a little bit harder to see the alignment.  4 is standard.)

Comment: If you're trying to use a regular text editor (which I assume you are based on the 3-space thing) it might seem like a lot of work to fix indentation in a big block of code, but if you get an IDE (there are good free ones out there; I use VS Code) you can fix indentation by just highlighting a chunk of code and hitting tab or shift-tab.

Comment: Also you can use the free tool `black` to automatically indent and format your code correctly

Comment: Suggestion: get rid of `play_again`. When you prompt the user to decide whether they want to play again, is the answer "no", `break` out of the loop, which can then just be `while True: ...`

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, your indentation has all code following the `while user not in rps:` loop *inside* of that loop. Rather you merely want to loop until you get valid input. This is just a matter of unindenting those lines one level.

```
play_again = True
while (play_again):

   import random
   import time
   
   rps = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")
   user = None #makes it so "user" can be called in while loop
   computer = random.choice(rps) #Picks 1 random option from the options variable
   
   while user not in rps: #if user enters something other than one of the options, prompts again
      user = input("Enter a choice: rock, paper, or scissors? ==> ")
   
   #print(user)
   #print(computer)
   
   if user == computer:
      print("You Chose: " + user)
      print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
      print("It's a tie!")
   elif (user == "rock" and computer == "scissors") or (user == "paper" and computer == "rock") or (user == "scissors" and computer == "paper"):
      print("You Chose: " + user)
      print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
      print("You win!")
   elif (user == "scissors" and computer == "rock") or (user == "rock" and computer == "paper") or (user == "paper" and computer == "scissors"):
      print("You Chose: " + user)
      print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
      print("You lost ;(")
         
   print() 
         
   question = None
   play_again_options = ("yes", "no")
   while question not in play_again_options:
      question = input("Do you want to play again? Type 'yes' or 'no' ==> ")
      if (question == "yes"):
         play_again = True
         print()
      elif (question == "no"):
         play_again = False
```

Because you need to select input from a user in more than one place from a limited number of options, you may wish to create a function to handle this.

Something like the following, perhaps:

```
def get_input(prompt, valid_options, error_msg=None):
   while True:
      inp = input(f"{prompt} Type {', '.join(valid_options[:-1])} or {valid_options[-1]} ")
      if inp in valid_options: return inp
      if error_msg: print(error_msg)
```

Which we can call like so:

```
>>> get_input("Do you want to play again?", ('yes', 'no'))
Do you want to play again? Type yes or no jddbhf
Do you want to play again? Type yes or no dkssfd
Do you want to play again? Type yes or no no
'no'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are not handling the case when user is not in rps:

```
if user == computer:
     print("You Chose: " + user)
     print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
     print("It's a tie!")
  elif (user == "rock" and computer == "scissors") or (user == "paper" and computer == "rock") or (user == "scissors" and computer == "paper"):
     print("You Chose: " + user)
     print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
     print("You win!")
  elif (user == "scissors" and computer == "rock") or (user == "rock" and computer == "paper") or (user == "paper" and computer == "scissors"):
     print("You Chose: " + user)
     print("The Computer Chose: " + computer)
     print("You lost ;(")
```

You should add an "else" case that use the instruction "continue". This instruction let you skip all the code above of it and tells the external while loop to start a new iteration. Something like this:

```
if user == computer:
     ....
else:
     continue
```

In your current code, your getting the question to continue playing because none of the conditions of your "if - elif" structure is satisfied but there is not any instruction that tells the program to skip the rest of the code, so you only need to add the missing case with that "continue" instruction.